# PSequel not showing table content on my 2020 mac

Tags: postgresql, psequel

first i create db in terminal, then i go to PSequel and add a connection with the local host.
after i create my table in the query and refresh it,

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id serial PRIMARY key, 
    name VARCHAR(100),
    email text UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    entries BIGINT DEFAULT 0,
    joined TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
    
);
```

it doesnt show anything on the content tab. Im using a 2020 MAC
[image]

Comment: you have no data in the table yet, add some rows

Comment: i did, check the code snipet above. I should have table with id, name, email, entries and joined

Comment: you just created the table, there is no data in it yet

Comment: oh i see what you mean, im gonna add some data now and see. thank you

Comment: not showing any data :/

Answer (score 1):

Theres a problem with the software. i enede up using dbeaver. very helpful

Comment: Glad I'm not the only one having issues and thanks for the suggestion. Greetings from another ZtM student.